# How to bring subview to front in interface builder without changing its position

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I want to ask a simple question how can I temporary bring a subview to front to view its element without changing its position by dragging and dropping. The problem i face all the time is i forgot to put the views back to there position and that causes lot of trouble specially if you are working on the view that have large number of subviews.

#### Question : Is there any shortcut or any functionality that can show the view temporary without dragging, changing its frame or making any changes in its hierarchy.

*For a view controller like this :-*

[image]

Comment: please try this... `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:YOUR_VIEW_NAME];`

Comment: There is no other way. just drag your view to the top of hierarchy and it will be visible to you in storyboard.

Comment: read the question first @NiravKotecha

Comment: i know that already lets see if someone come up with a solution @VirenMalhan

Comment: If you don't need it, temporarily put top-most view alpha value to zero (0). That will do the trick since views with very low alpha are not responsive. Hope this helps.

Comment: in that case i could simple drag the view above the last view to view it then undo all the actions, what if you have 50-60 subviews and you forgot to set the alpha back to 1? all these process take lots of time and testing too. my point of asking the question was is there any shortcut that can just give me the view of a subview that is in the bottom hierarchy. @manta

Answer (score 7):

FYI, for those who are wondering, the view closest to the bottom of the list (on the left) will show in the front. So in the case below, view 'a' will be in front of 'b' and 'b' will be in front of 'c'

XIB:
[image: XIB]

Answer (score 2):

If you need your views to be readily accessible for viewing/editing without having to rearrange them, I would actually recommend breaking them out into their own view and then stitching them together in the correct order in your code. This will ensure that all elements will be put in the proper order and will always be easily editable. Something like this:

[image: Interface Builder]

And then in your code, in somewhere like `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.view addSubview:view2];
[self.view addSubview:view3];
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but i have clearly mentioned in my question i want to do it in interface builder and just for a quick review of view, there are so many ways to do that and i know them too.

Comment: @dreamBegin If you're just looking for a quick review and don't need to do any editing, just drag the view in question out to the canvas of IB to check it, and then ctrl-z to put it back.

Comment: I know this already as i have mentioned already in the question but sometimes things get heavy if we forgot to do ctrl-z. i wanted to know that time if there is a shortcut or something like where we hold a key and select the view the view gets highlighted but I'm confirmed now there is no such type of functionality in X-Code. By the way i appreciate your efforts.